# Solve that $3 \sec θ = 4 \cos θ$.

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation

$$3 \sec θ = 4 \cos θ \text{ where ;  }0 \leq \theta \leq 90$$

Help find and explain theta.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $\sec{\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}$.

Comment: Do you mean to associate this with angles or radians? Angles give $\theta = 30^\circ$ but radians give $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with the equation
$$\tag{1}
3\sec\theta =4\cos\theta.
$$
Since $\sec\theta={1\over \cos\theta}$, equation $(1)$ is equivalent to the equation
$$
\tag{2} {3\over\cos\theta}=4\cos\theta.
$$
By "equivalent", I mean that $\theta$ is a solution of equation $(1)$ if and only if it is a solution of equation $(2)$.
It seems that multiplying both sides of $(2)$ by $\cos\theta$ would simplify matters. This would give
$$\tag{3}
3=4\cos^2\theta
$$
But wait, is equation $(3)$ equivalent to equation $(2)$? We need to be concerned with what happens if $\cos\theta=0$. Here the left hand side of equation $(2)$ is not defined when $\cos\theta=0$. On the other hand $\cos\theta=0$ does not lead to a solution of equation $(3)$. So, indeed, equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equivalent: multiplication by $\cos\theta$ is valid when it is not zero, and when $\cos\theta=0$, neither $(2)$ nor $(3)$ have a solution.

Ok then, we need to solve $(3)$.  Dividing both sides by $4$ gives
$$\tag{4}
\cos^2\theta={3\over4}.
$$
Taking the square roots of both sides gives
$$
|\cos\theta|=\sqrt3/2.
$$
Since we know $0^\circ\le\theta\le90^\circ$, we know that $|\cos\theta|=\cos\theta$ (the cosine function is nonnegative in the first quadrant), so we have to find the value(s) of $\theta$ in $[0^\circ,90^\circ]$ for which
$$
\cos\theta =\sqrt3/2.
$$

You should recognize that there is only one solution here, namely $\theta=30^\circ$ (you're dealing with one of the "special angles", here).

Answer (score 5):

Hint. $3\sec \theta = 4\cos \theta$ is the same $4 \cos^2\theta - 3 =0$.

Comment: This is true because $\sec{\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos{\theta}}$. Thus, $\frac{3}{\cos{\theta}}=4\cos{\theta}$

Answer (score 3):

$$3 \sec \theta = 4 \cos \theta$$

$$3 \cos  \theta \sec \theta = 4 \cos  \theta\cos \theta$$

$$3   = 4 \cos ^2 \theta$$

$${3 \over 4}   =  \cos ^2 \theta$$

$$\pm{\sqrt 3 \over 2}   =  \cos  \theta$$

The solutions are all angles related to $\pi/6$ and $11\pi/6$ for the positive solution,  and to $5\pi/6$ and $7\pi/6$ for the negative solution, by multiples of $2\pi$.

In your case you only want $\pi/6$

Answer (score 2):

You got: $$\sec\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$ therefore your equation becomes: $$\frac{3}{4}=\cos^2\theta\Leftrightarrow\frac{3}{4}-\cos^2\theta=0\Leftrightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\cos\theta\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\cos\theta\right) =0$$Since $0 \leq \theta \leq 90$, $\cos\theta$ is positive, hence: $$\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Leftrightarrow\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: You could use `\cos{blah}` and `\sin{blah}` to get non italic function names $\sin$ and $\cos$, and `\left` and `\right` to get delimiters that adapt to their content. compare $$({\sqrt 3 \over 2}-cos\theta)$$ `({\sqrt 3 \over 2}-cos\theta)` to $$\left({\sqrt 3 \over 2}-\cos\theta \right)$$ `\left({\sqrt 3 \over 2}-\cos\theta \right)`

Comment: It is usually a convention to use function names without italics.

Comment: Ok then, i'll change them!Thanks for the delimiters tip!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3}{\cos \theta}=4 \cos \theta \Rightarrow \frac{4\cos^2 \theta-3}{\cos \theta}=0 \Rightarrow (2\cos \theta-\sqrt 3)(2\cos \theta+\sqrt 3)=0$$

Hence :

$\cos \theta = \frac{-\sqrt 3}{2} ~\text{or}~ \cos \theta =\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$

Since $\theta$ belongs to the first quadrant we have :

$\theta =\frac{\pi}{6}$